# Why is python not processing my strip code

Tags: python

I was trying to see if I could make a code that has a valid URL, specifically about filtering symbols not available in the URL, when I came to this...

```
url = "https:testurl.com/"
na = [':', '/', '.']
for i in na:
  l = l.strip(i)
  print(l)
```

Does anybody know the solution to this? Or any other solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean. Are you trying to check if a string is URL safe?

Comment: what is ```l```? i think you should use ```url``` instead and of course I think you should use ```split``` instead of ```strip``` and of course you cant use for loop in this way!

Comment: "Does anybody know the solution to this?" You need to tell us what problem you had. Was there an error message? Did you get a different output than you expected?

Comment: You can't use `l = l.strip(i)` before defining `l`. You'll get this error: `NameError: name 'l' is not defined`.

Comment: @Kemp there is no name error, when I do that, it just acts as if that never even happened

Comment: @Pyzard sorry I didn't changed it in a rush; l should be url.

Comment: @AKiani but I am trying to strip out a letter, not making it in to a list... unless if you want me to join it like..
for i in na:
  'i'.split(url)
  ''.join(url)

?

Comment: `strip` only removes characters from the start and end of the string. Did you mean to use `url.replace(i, '')`?

Comment: @Kemp that is not working for me. It also just don't "Process it". I don't know if you can see this... file:///home/chronos/u-c5294e906797acbfa006c8ec884d65fc3767fa7f/MyFiles/Downloads/Screenshot%202021-03-24%209.09.49%20AM.png

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the url begins with `https://` (so a valid link) like this.

```
url = "https://testurl.com/"
if url[0:8] == "https://":
    print("valid url: " + url)
else:
    pass
```